# HTTPServer recebe OPTIONS do Axios e vue-resource

Tags: python-3.x, http

Quando envio uma requisição com o Axios ou Vue-Resource, com o server http acabo recebendo um OPTIONS em vez do DELETE, POST, ou PUT.

Requisições:

```
this.$axios.put('http://192.168.0.103:3389', {teste: 'teste'}).then(function (res) {
    console.log('RESULTADO:', res.data)
    self.users = res.data
})

this.$http.delete('http://192.168.0.103:3389').then(function (res) {
    console.log('RESULTADO:', res.body)
    self.users = res.body
})
```

server.py

```
from http.server import *
import json

class Server():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    SERVER = Server()

    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "*")
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({'OPTIONS': 'teste'}).encode('utf-8'))
    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "*")
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({'POST': 'teste'}).encode('utf-8'))

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "*")
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({'GET': 'teste'}).encode('utf-8'))

    def do_PUT(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "*")
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({'PUT': 'teste'}).encode('utf-8'))

    def do_DELETE(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "*")
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({'DELETE': 'teste'}).encode('utf-8'))

httpd = HTTPServer(192;168;0;103, 3389), Server)
print('Open in', httpd.server_address)
httpd.serve_forever()
```